# Check if folder in TFS has changes in Command Line

Tags: tfs

Is it possible, through the command line (e.g. tf.exe) to check if there are new changes within a specific directory?

My hope is to have a script that will automatically merge certain folders if they have changes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [Tf Command-Line Utility Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN? Probably "Folderdiff Command" is what you want. Example

```
C:>tf folderdiff $/serverFolder F:\localFolder /recursive /noprompt
```

Comment: This feature is incredibly slow. To diff every single file in a folder recursively instead of checking if there was a revision in this folder takes a very, very long time. Do you know of a way to check my revision # any revisions made in a particular folder?